# Date object in safari

Tags: javascript

I am using safari 8.0, And I try to do

```
 new Date('sat-oct-10-2015');
```

on chrome the result is Date object with the right date. But on safari the result is

```
 Invalid Date
```

how can I work with dates in this format in safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the Date constructor (or *Date.parse*) to parse strings. Until ES5, parsing of date strings was entirely implementation dependent. After that, the long form of ISO 8606 has been specified, however parts of that changed with ECMAScript 2015 so that even using specified formats is not consistent across browsers (e.g. 2015-10-15 12:00:00 may result in 3 different results in browsers currently in use).

The solution is to manually parse date strings, either write your own function (which is not difficult if you only need to support one format) or use a small library.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use the [standard date format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) specified by ECMAScript  ISO format.

`Date.parse()` i.e [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) constructor will always produce the expected result if you use the standard string format. Also the browser may support additional string formats, but that may not  be supported by all other browser vendors.

Comment: Parsing with the Date constructor is not recommended as not all browsers will parse even ISO 8601 dates, e.g. IE 8 (which still has around 8% useage at the moment, which is more than all versions of Safari combined).

Answer (score 1):

When creating a `Date` object with a “human-readable” string, you must use a certain format, usually conforming to RFC2822 or ISO 8601.

It may be that a browser is able to process your `new Date('sat-oct-10-2015');`, but this is not demanded by the specifications.

Hint: Look at [some other ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to create a date object, for example with a Unix timestamp. This is easier and more reliable than the `dateString` approach.

Comment: No, don't do that. Don't use the built–in functions for parsing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for dates in JavaScript. Then you can simply parse the date with

```
moment('sat-oct-10-2015', 'ddd-MMM-DD-YYYY').format();
```

moments API has good support in all major browsers and eases date manipulating and displaying with JavaScript.